# CSV File Generation

Tags: java, spring, csv

```
    public class csvFileDownload {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        Student s2 = new Student(11, "Sachin", 30);
        Student s3 = new Student(12, "Vikas", 40);
        Student s4 = new Student(10, "Harkirat", 20);


        List<Student> std = Arrays.asList(s4,s2,s3);



        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("students.csv",true);

        writeToCSV(std, fileWriter);
        writeToCSV(std, fileWriter);
        fileWriter.close();



    }


    private void writeToCSV(List<Student> std, Writer writer) throws IOException {
        // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
        ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(writer,
                CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        String[] header = {"Id", "Name", "Age"};
        csvWriter.writeHeader(header);

        for (Student aStudent : std) {
            csvWriter.write(aStudent, header);
        }
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```

I am writing this program and getting the CSV file and appending it. But i am getting same header. How can i remove the same header and how can i reform the code more into simple.
Output

```
Id,Name,Age
10,Harkirat,20
11,Sachin,30
12,Vikas,40
Id,Name,Age
10,Harkirat,20
11,Sachin,30
12,Vikas,40
```

Comment: aren't you calling writeToCSV twice in a row? Surely that's not what you want to do.

Comment: Ya. i am calling it twice in order to append the data in CSV but with getting header one time

Comment: because you call two time method header in there so it' has print two time

Comment: Yes , i am calling the method twice but i want it should display the header only once.

Comment: make separate method for header that call once and that's fine

Comment: Can you please tell how ? i am doing this but didnt getting the answer. @DivyeshKanzariya

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
 public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("students.csv",true);

    // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
    ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(fileWriter,
            CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

    String[] header = {"Id", "Name", "Age"};
    csvWriter.writeHeader(header);

    List<Student> sList = getStudents();
    writeToCSV(sList, csvWriter);

    icbw.close();
    fileWriter.close();
}

private List<Student> getStudents()
{
    Student s2 = new Student(11, "Sachin", 30);
    Student s3 = new Student(12, "Vikas", 40);
    Student s4 = new Student(10, "Harkirat", 20);

    return Arrays.asList(s4,s2,s3);
}


private void writeToCSV(List<Student> std, ICsvBeanWriter icbw) throws IOException {
    for (Student aStudent : std) {
        icbw.write(aStudent, header);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not writing anything to the csv file.

Comment: I did not test the code, I was simply providing you an alternate structure for you code.  I have updated two errors I found.  One was a missing semicolon after the writeToCSV, which is probably the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: Ya i had also fixed that . But its not generating error and not writing anything to the file

Comment: Well I don't have all of the classes necessary to run this, have you tried running a debugger through it to see what it is doing?

Comment: This was also just a suggestion, there may be easier ways to do it, especially as you already had code that was partially working.  What this example is trying to show is that by grouping things differently you can get cleaner code and hopefully cleaner results.  If it is not working, start with the code that is at least writing to a file and then make one change at a time.  For example, move the generation of the student data to a function, first.

Comment: Can i append the data with same header. How ?

Comment: Look at the getStudents method.  It is not adding a header there.  The Header is added only once in the downloadCSV method.   If you want to add more sets of students you need probably need to implement a factory design pattern for your students and a Class to generate each the List of Student.

Comment: How can i make the file at runtime , means i will give only filename and it make its own

Comment: You might want to ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a flag which controls whether the header is written.

```
public class csvFileDownload {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/downloadCSV")
    public void downloadCSV(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        Student s2 = new Student(11, "Sachin", 30);
        Student s3 = new Student(12, "Vikas", 40);
        Student s4 = new Student(10, "Harkirat", 20);

        List<Student> std = Arrays.asList(s4, s2, s3);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("students.csv", true);

        writeToCSV(std, fileWriter, true);
        writeToCSV(std, fileWriter, false);
        fileWriter.close();

    }

    private void writeToCSV(List<Student> std, Writer writer, boolean writeHeader) throws IOException {
        // uses the Super CSV API to generate CSV data from the model data
        ICsvBeanWriter csvWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(writer, CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        String[] header = { "Id", "Name", "Age" };
        if(writeHeader) csvWriter.writeHeader(header);

        for (Student aStudent : std) {
            csvWriter.write(aStudent, header);
        }
        csvWriter.close();
    }
}
```